# How to write jpql for entity + a count off that entity?

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql, entitymanager

I have a class `Batch` which among other properties has a list samples (of type `List<Sample>`). This list is mapped via a many-to-one relation (Sample 1->n Batch). I need to be able to fetch all batches along with the amount of samples in each one. How would I do this without having to do n+1 queries?

Also, how do I map it to objects?

```
TypedQuery<Batch> query = entityManager.createQuery("select b from Batch b"Batch.class);
List<Batch> batches = query.getResultList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Batch  has a property which type is `List<Sample>` , the relationship of Batch to Sample is one-to-many . You should annotate `@OneToMany` on the `List<Sample>` inside the `Batch` and annotate `@ManyToOne` on Batch  property inside the Sample.

To avoid n+1 problem , you can use fetch join to fetch the Batch along with its list of sample .It will cause hibernate to generate a left join of Batch and Sample such that the returned Batch instance have their sample list fully initialized.

```
SELECT batch  FROM Batch batch join fetch batch.sampleList;
```